# Django ModelForm Validation: Is it a security risk to set an object field before validating the dependent form data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have two questions regarding **Django ModelForm validation** behavior that has perplexed me.

**Issue 1: Manually Assinging Model Field Before Form Validation:**
I have a `Listing` model set up for an e-commerce app:

**Models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, DecimalValidator
from decimal import Decimal


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Listing(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        ("APPAREL", "Apparel"),
        ("COLLECTIBLES", "Collectibles"),
        ("COMICS", "Comics"),
        ("MEMORABILIA", "Sports Memorabilia"),
        ("SNEAKERS", "Sneakers"),
        ("TRADING_CARDS", "Trading Cards"),
        ("OTHER", "Other")
    ]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    starting_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2,validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
    current_bid = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=11, decimal_places=2,validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
    image = models.URLField(blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

I am excluding `current_bid` from my ModelForm, as I am setting `current_bid` equal to the `starting_bid` value entered into the form by the user for each new `Listing`. Originally, I did this (per below) repeating the `.save()` command, which seemed to be a poor solution – though Django's docs does this in certain examples:

**views.py – Validating Form *Before* Manually Assigning Field**

```
def create_listing(request):
    class NewListingForm(ModelForm):
        template_name = "auctions/form_template.html"
        class Meta:
            model = Listing
            exclude = ["current_bid"]
            widgets = {
                "description": forms.Textarea(attrs={"placeholder": "Enter a description for your new listing..."}),
                "title": forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Enter new listing title..."}),
                "starting_bid":forms.NumberInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Minimum $0.00"})
            }
            labels = {
                "title": _("Enter Listing Title:"),
                "description": _("Enter Listing Item Description:"),
                "starting_bid": _("Enter Starting Bid:"),
                "image": _("Upload Image URL for Listing"),
                "category": _("Select Listing Category")
            }
            error_messages = {
                "title": {
                    "max_length": _("Listing title must not exceed 80 characters")
                },
                "description": {
                    "max_length": _("Listing description must not exceed 400 characters")
                },
                "starting_bid": {
                    "min_value": _("Minimum starting bid must be at least $0.00")
                }
            }

    if request.method == "POST":
        new_listing_form = NewListingForm(request.POST)
        if new_listing_form.is_valid():
            title = new_listing_form.cleaned_data["title"]
            starting_bid = new_listing_form.cleaned_data["starting_bid"]
            try:
                new_listing_form.save()
            except ValidationError as validationerror:
                return render (request, "auctions/create.html", {
                    "validation_error": validationerror,
                    "form": new_listing_form
                })
            new_listing_object = Listing.objects.get(title=title)
            setattr(new_listing_object, "current_bid", starting_bid)
            new_listing_object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=[new_listing_object.pk]))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
                "form": new_listing_form
            })
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
        "form": NewListingForm()
    })
```

Therefore, as a solution to the above, is there a risk to manually updating the `starting_bid` with the `current_bid` submitted with the form, before validating the form data with `is_valid()`? I know calling `.save()` does validation as well, so is it a non-issue?

**views.py – Changes to views.py Without Validation first**

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        listing = Listing(current_bid=request.POST["starting_bid"])
        new_listing_form = NewListingForm(request.POST, instance=listing)
        if new_listing_form.is_valid():
            try:
                title = new_listing_form.cleaned_data["title"]
                new_listing_form.save()
            except ValidationError as validationerror:
                return render (request, "auctions/create.html", {
                    "validation_error": validationerror,
                    "form": new_listing_form
                })
            new_listing_object = Listing.objects.get(title=title)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=[new_listing_object.pk]))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
                "form": new_listing_form
            })
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
        "form": NewListingForm()
    })
```

I also realize there are multiple ways to do similar things, such as `.update()` or `.save(commit=false)` or **F Expressions**, though they can be used for other scenarios, so I'm wondering which might be best?

**Issue 2: DecimalField (`starting_bid`) Not Preventing Integer Values**

Lastly, I have a small separate issue regarding the `DecimalField` ModelForm validation for the `starting_bid` field. Initially, using what I believe to be almost identical code, I wanted the user to be able to submit a *non-decimal* value such as `10` for the `starting_bid` field in the **ModelForm**, which I *thought* was causing an error because of my `current_bid` model in **models.py**:

```
current_bid = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=11, decimal_places=2,validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
```

So instead, I was excepting the error as `validationerror` in **views.py**. However, now, the model ***IS*** allowing me to submit non-decimal values, but I don't understand why? Even though there's nothing different that I am noticing in my code?